# mediaelement not playing

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

Im trying to play a wmv video on the home page of a Silverligh Navigation Application, but it won't start playing. I've stored the file in the clientbin folder and changed the build action to resource.

```
<Canvas Name="Holder" Width="350" Height="220" Background="Black">
    <MediaElement Name="Video" AutoPlay="True" Volume="100" Source="vid.wmv"/>
</Canvas>
```

Additionally I've tried making a button and add a Video.Play() method but still no luck... When I play the file using WMP it works perfect.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite probably an exception being thrown while attempting to load the video.  Add a handler to the `MediaFailed` event of your MediaElement and see what the exception you get from inside the `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs` parameter is.

Comment: And for anyone who wants to know what that error means, see Glenn's follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9648734.