# mediaelement error

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

When I try to load my video, it won't play. The error I'm getting for the mediafailed event is: 3016 AG_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE. It's a wmv file which is supported and I can play it with windows media player without a problem.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all media types are supported, not even all wmvs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(v=vs.95).aspx

You could perhaps try to convert it to an appropriate media type.

Also, make sure it's a resource file.  To do this, right click and get the properties of the file in the project, and set it's "build action" property to "resource".  I also say "copy if newer" for the "copy to output directory" property.